# addition of variables combined with >/< test BASH

Tags: bash, awk, grep, compare, addition

So i am trying to write a bash script to check if all values in a data set are within a certain margin of the average.

so far:

```
    #!/bin/bash
cat massbuild.csv
while IFS=, read col1 col2
do
x=$(grep "$col2" $col1.pdb | grep "HETATM" | awk '{ sum += $7; n++ } END { if (n > 0) print sum / n; }')


i=$(grep "$col2" $col1.pdb | grep "HETATM" | awk '{print $7;}')


if $(($i > $[$x + 15])); then
echo "OUTSIDE THE RANGE!"
fi

done < massbuild.csv
```

So far, I have broken it down by components to test, and have found the values of x and i read correctly, but it seems that adding 15 to x, or the comparison to i doesn't work.

I have read around online and i am stumped =/

Comment: A UNIX shell (e.g. bash) is an environment from which to call tools to do specific jobs, with a language to let you sequence those calls. The UNIX tool to manipulate text is awk. So, your approach should be to have bash call awk on your input file, and your script should be written in awk. Post some sample input and expected output for more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without sample input and expected output we're just guessing but MAYBE this is the right starting point for your script (untested, of course, since no in/out provided):

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F, '
NR==FNR {
    file = $1 ".pdb"
    ARGV[ARGC] = file
    file2col2s[file] = (col1to2s[file] ? file2col2s[file] FS : "") $2
    next
}

FNR==1 { split(file2col2s[FILENAME],col2s) }

/HETATM/ {
    for (i=1;i in col2s;i++) {
        col2 = col2s[i]
        if ($0 ~ col2) {
            sum[FILENAME,col2] += $7
            cnt[FILENAME,col2]++
        }
    }
}

END {
    for (file in file2col2s) {
        split(file2col2s[file],col2s)
        for (i=1;i in col2s;i++) {
            col2 = col2s[i]
            print sum[file,col2]
            print cnt[file,col2]
        }
    }
}
' massbuild.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
a=4; b=0; if [ "$a" -lt "$(( $b + 5 ))" ]; then echo "a < b + 5"; else echo "a >= b + 5"; fi
```

Ref: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

Comment: @Avinash Raj Thanks! but i still get the error "[: : integer expression expected"

Comment: @user3403864 I'm not the answerer. I just modified what Satya is posted.